# Quartz - While doing transaction in hibernate with spring, Exception occurs

Tags: java, facebook, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I am coding one facebook application.  Once user authorize my app @ fb,  their  landing page would be view-profile page.  Though I pulling lots of data viz., likes, groups etc.. It takes lots of time to redirect him to landing page.  So what I thought is, Just get user email ID, educational and employment details then redirect him to landing page.  Mean gap I started a thread before redirection, which will pull all the data from his account in background.  So I created a class which implements runnable, then I started that thread from controller.  It works fine until I get the data from fb.  While calling DAO's save(obj) method I am getting the following error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

One of my friend suggested me to go with quartz scheduler.  So Here is what I tried.

**FBController:**

```
                SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Scheduler shed = null;
                try {
                    shed = sf.getScheduler();
                    shed.start();
                } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("FB_Details", null, FacebookControllerHelper.class);

                jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("Users", user);
                jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("accessToken", accessToken);
                jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("fbService", facebookService);
                jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("OAuth", service);


                Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger(0, 1);
                trigger.setName("FB_Details");
                try {
                    shed.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
                } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                    System.out.println("Ended In Exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

**FBControllerHelper:**

```
public class FacebookControllerHelper implements Job{

    private Users users;
    private Token accessToken;
    private FacebookService facebookService;
    private OAuthService service;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL_LIKE = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=likes.limit(1000).fields(id,name,description,website)";

    public FacebookControllerHelper(){
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
              throws JobExecutionException{

        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();

        users = (Users) dataMap.get("Users"); 
        accessToken = (Token) dataMap.get("accessToken");
        facebookService = (FacebookService) dataMap.get("fbService");
        service = (OAuthService) dataMap.get("OAuth");

        this.getUserLikes(accessToken, users);
    } 

    @Transactional
    public void getUserLikes(Token accessToken, Users user){
        System.out.println("Entering getUserLikes Method");

        OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL_LIKE);
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        Response response = request.send();

        FBUserLikes fbuserLikes = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), FBUserLikes.class);
        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        facebookService.saveUserLikes(user, fbuserLikes);
    }
}
```

`response.getBody()` is printing what json it got from facbook.  But while passing it to service, there I am calling DAO'S save() method.  At that point I am getting the following error,

```
[ERROR] [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.FB_Details threw an unhandled Exception: 
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
```

I googled my error and I got some solution, which doesn't suits my application.  I am using spring 3.0.5 Version and quartz 1.8.6.  And many blogs and similar results shows me how to run a cron job in a particular interval.  But that is of no use for me.  I would be grateful if some one help me out to solve this issue.   Hope my question is clear.

Thankyou in Advance.

Comment: You should configure the QuartzScheduler as a spring bean. Instantiating a scheduler method doesn't make sense. [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html) makes it easy to configure a scheduler in spring. And by the way, if you are only using quartz to make some processing asynchronous, using the quartz framework is overkill. Check Spring's [@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support) for example.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you call transational method from the same controller. Spring needs to create proxy for transational annotation. You can do it by autowiring or by getting bean from spring context, but then you have to move your this method to seperate class.

Another (dirty) solution is creating hibernate session directly in method.

Comment: Clearly read my question then post your answer.  I mentioned FBController is one file and FBControllerHelper is another. "The reason is that you call transational method from the same controller."  It is not as you said.

Comment: Is directly as I said. You execute FBControllerHelper from FBController. But you call getUserLikes from FBController. Try move out this method to another class for example to facebookService and then call it in your FBControllerHelper. If you don't even try then sorry.

Comment: For test you can move @Transactional annotation to facebookService.saveUserLikes(user, fbuserLikes);

Comment: Hmmm.. It makes sense.  I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

The `HibernateException` is thrown because there isn't a transaction in progress.

The `@Transactional` on `FacebookControllerHelper.getUserLikes(Token accessToken, Users user)` won't work. Spring uses [proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) to implement to transactional behavior. But in order for this to work, the lifecycle of the `FacebookControllerHelper` should be managed by spring, which is not the case as Quartz instantiates the `FacebookControllerHelper` job. You could use [aspectj](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj) to proxy objects managed outside of spring, but this probably a bit to complicated for your use case.

The real problem is probably that neither your service or dao is transactional. The facebook service and dao are probably managed by spring, so you should make at least the dao or service [transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations). Declaring transactions on your service layer is a good practice anyway.

If you really want to make the `FacebookControllerHelper` transactional,you should use aspectj, use a `TransactionTemplate` or let spring manage the lifecycle of your jobs by configuring a custom `SchedulerFactory`.